Find a base b in which $\left( 45 \right)_{b}$ and $\left( 55 \right)_{b}$ are squares of consecutive integers
I started with
$$(i) \hspace{5 mm}\left( 55 \right)_{b}-\left(45  \right)_{b}=\left(10 \right)_{b}=\left( b  \right)_{10}$$
$$(ii) \hspace{5 mm} \left(x+1 \right)_{b}^2- \left( x \right)_{b}^2=\left( 2x\right)_{b}  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \left( 2x\right)_{b}=\left(10 \right)_{b}     $$
$$ \Rightarrow \left( x\right)_{b}=\left(5 \right)_{b}     $$
This means that $ b \gt 5$.
With trial and error i checked for :
$(i) \hspace{2mm} b=6 $ and $ 5^2-4^2 $
$(ii)  \hspace{2mm} b=7 $ and $ 6^2-5^2 $
$(iii)  \hspace{2mm} b=8 $ and $ 7^2-6^2 $
but none of the above was right.

I think the problem means consecutive integers in base $10$. Anyway, $(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1$ (you forgot $+1$). Try again after fixing this mistake and in case let me know if you need the solution

Numbers $45$ and $55$, are in base $10$ or in base $b$? Clarify this point.

I quoted the question as it is written in the book. $45$ and $55$ are in base $b$. My understanding is that the number requested (i.e $x$) is in base $b$ But from the answer of  @ChrisLewis  i see that $x$ it is most probably in base 10.

We're looking to solve
$$4b+5=x^2,\quad 5b+5=(x+1)^2$$
for integers $b$ and $x$.
Eliminating $x$ will lead to unpleasant algebra, so let's try eliminating $b$:
\begin{align}
20b+25&=5x^2\\
20b+20&=4(x+1)^2\\
5&=x^2-8x-4 \\
x^2-8x-9&=0 \\
(x-9)(x+1)&=0
\end{align}
With $x=-1$, we get $b=-1$, which doesn't work as a base. With $x=9$, we have $b=19$, which is the only valid solution.

Simpler: subtract them $\Rightarrow b=2x!+!1,$ plugged into first $\Rightarrow 0=x^2!-!8x!-!9=(x!-!9)(x!+!1)\ \ $

A slightly different line of attack:
Let $4b+5=n^2$ so that $5b+5=(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$. Subtracting the first equation from the second gives
$b=2n+1\implies n=(b-1)/2$
So
$4b+5=(b-1)^2/4$
$16b+20=b^2-2b+1$
$b^2-18b-19=0$
which has one positive root $b=19$.
